# how to merge array inside another array objects in one array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am looking to merge array inside another array objects in one array in javascript. I tried many way like concat and join methods but I couldn't get it
I have array below array which I need to merge into one array

```
  arr =  [
        [{
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            },
            {
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            }
        ],
        [{
            PRODUCE: 'Apple',
            STATE: 'CP',
            COUNTRY: 'US'
        }]

    ]
```

I want result as below

```
[
    {
        PRODUCE: 'Apple',
        STATE: 'CA',
        COUNTRY: 'US'
    },
    {
        PRODUCE: 'Apple',
        STATE: 'CA',
        COUNTRY: 'US'
    },
    {
        PRODUCE: 'Apple',
        STATE: 'CP',
        COUNTRY: 'US'
    }
]
```

Comment: use Array.flat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to use modern javascript, you can try:

```
arr.flat()
```

More info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

If not, you can just use lodash, underscore or ramda. Libraries with useful utilities.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten

Answer (score 2):

You can use *flat()* for this

> The flat() method creates a new array with all sub-array elements
> concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

Here you can read more about it

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

```js
const arr = [
  [{
      PRODUCE: 'Apple',
      STATE: 'CA',
      COUNTRY: 'US'
    },
    {
      PRODUCE: 'Apple',
      STATE: 'CA',
      COUNTRY: 'US'
    }
  ],
  [{
    PRODUCE: 'Apple',
    STATE: 'CP',
    COUNTRY: 'US'
  }]

]

console.log(arr.flat());
```

Comment: thanks @Aalex however couldn't find method flat()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.flat()`.

> var newArray = arr.flat([depth]);

```js
    const arr =  [
        [{
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            },
            {
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            }
        ],
        [{
            PRODUCE: 'Apple',
            STATE: 'CP',
            COUNTRY: 'US'
        }]

    ]
    console.log(arr.flat())
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple Approach, using spread operator and forEach loop

```js
const arr =  [
        [{
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            },
            {
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            }
        ],
        [{
            PRODUCE: 'Apple',
            STATE: 'CP',
            COUNTRY: 'US'
        }]

    ]
    let result = [];
    arr.forEach((item)=>{
     if(Array.isArray(item)){
       result = [...result,...item]
     }
     else{
        result = [...result,item]
     }
    }
    )
    console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two flat() answer, but alternative code that you tried for concat(), you can try like this:

```js
var arr =  [
        [{
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            },
            {
                PRODUCE: 'Apple',
                STATE: 'CA',
                COUNTRY: 'US'
            }
        ],
        [{
            PRODUCE: 'Apple',
            STATE: 'CP',
            COUNTRY: 'US'
        }]

    ]
    
var newArray = arr[1].concat(arr[0]);

console.log(newArray);
```